# Creating single input stream for multiple files in a hadoop path - Java

Tags: java, stream, hdfs, inputstream, fileinputstream

I want to create a single input stream for multiple files in the HDFS path. The HDFS Path contains many data files (eg: data-1, data-2, ....data-n). It also contains the _SUCCESS file. I want to create a single input stream for all the data files execluding the _SUCCESS file.

Right now, I am going into loop through FileStatus and create an input stream for individual files. I merge these input streams to create a sequenceStream.

Below is the sample of my code:

```
Path filePath = new Path(hdfsPath);
hdfsFS = FileSystem.get(conf);

CharSequence fileNameFormat = "data";
FileStatus[] inputFiles = hdfsFS.listStatus(filePath);

Vector<InputStream> inputStreams = new Vector<InputStream>();


for (int i =0; i < inputFiles.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(inputFiles[i].getPath().getName());

    if (inputFiles[i].getPath().getName().contains(fileNameFormat)) {

        Path fileName = new Path(hdfsPath + inputFiles[i].getPath().getName());
        fileInputStream = hdfsFS.open(fileName);

        inputStreams.add(fileInputStream);

    }
}

Enumeration<InputStream> enu = inputStreams.elements();
sequenceStream = new SequenceInputStream(enu);
```

I want to create input stream, I do not want to put any file to local and then create an input stream. Is there any other efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not want to put any file to local " ? (your (posted) code doesn't put anything to local)

Comment: What I meant is I do not want to create any physical copy of the file at any point in the process. My code uses sequencestream without making any physical copy of file.